# how to add subscribers without using shortcode in send press

Tags: wordpress

I am using sendpress plugin. I want to add subscribers through code without using sendpress shortcode .like i have checkbox signup for news letter if it is checked email address will automatically added to newsletter plugin database

Answer (score 0):

Use Sendpress:SUBSCRIBE-user() function which takes email and listid as an argument which updates all table in sendpress.